# Cant Start App Due to Errors

Tags: android

I keep getting these two errors which stop me from running my app

```
Description error: Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)   AndroidManifest.xml /SMSLookup  line 6  Android AAPT Problem

Description The element type "manifest" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</manifest>".   AndroidManifest.xml /SMSLookup  line 14 Android XML Format Problem
```

Here  is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.xenom.sms"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" />
    <activity android:name=".SMSLookupActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
</manifest>
```

Can anyone help me identify the problem?

Answer (score 5):

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" />
```

Looks wrong: you're closing that `<application>` tag right there, and closing it again near the end.